# Run an AppleScript by using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I need to run an AppleScript using a keyboard shortcut. How can I do that?

I think about

1. Save AppleScript in textual format.
2. Use Keyboard Maestro to launch 'osascript' to run the script when the matching keyboard shortcut is called.

What do you think? Is there better way to go?

Comment: This can be done without third party apps, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/247183/207332

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A program like Keyboard Maestro can do exactly as you said, but instead of saving the AppleScript as just regular text you can save it as a script (.scpt) and just pass the path to `osascript`.

A program that I've used off and on that is designed to do this specifically is Red Sweater Software's [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/). It's free for up to 10 keyboard shortcuts. Otherwise I've just used [LaunchBar](http://obdev.at/products/launchbar) (while others would recommend other app launchers)

Comment: +1 for FastScripts, i use it daily to save HTML pages to PDFs in a predefined folder.

Comment: FastScript seems good. BTW, can it run python/ruby scripts also?

Comment: @prosseek: Yes.

Answer (score 2):

I do it with [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/) to launch a script that opens a Terminal window at the same place the foremost Finder window is.

Triggers -> [+] -> HotKey, then select your script, and choose the "Execute" action.

It's probably similar to using Keyboard Maestro, and said software might be simpler. Though, I already had Quicksilver installed when I did this, so reusing it was better.